# How do I read a custom error message returned when HttpWebRequest.GetResponse throws a WebException?

Tags: c#, .net-core

I've a NET.Core API with simple test method:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> TestApi()
{
    try
    {
        throw new UnauthorizedAccessException("My custom error");

        return Ok();
    }
    catch (UnauthorizedAccessException ex)
    {
        return StatusCode(401,ex.Message);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        throw;
    }

}
```

I need to retrieve the message from a client like this:

```
var request = WebRequest.Create($"{baseUrl}{url}") as HttpWebRequest;
request.Method = "POST";
request.ContentType = "application/json";
request.Expect = "application/json";
request.ContentLength = 0;

if (parameters != null)
{
    request.ContentLength = serializedObject.Length;
    using (var writer = new StreamWriter(request.GetRequestStream()))
    {
        writer.Write(serializedObject);
    }
}

var response = request.GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse;
var responseEncoding = Encoding.GetEncoding(response.CharacterSet);

using (var sr = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream(), responseEncoding))
{
    var result = sr.ReadToEnd();
    return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(result);
}
```

Now `request.GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse` returns me:

```
The remote server returned an error: (401) Unauthorized.
```

[image]

instead of `My custom error`. Can someone point me in the right direction?

Comment: Have you looked at the inner exception?

Comment: InnerException is `null` and there are no additional info in `Response` object.

Comment: Look in the `Response` property. In particular, `Response.StatusDescription`. The message you see isn't getting returned from your API. Your API returns a 401 and `GetResponse` throws an exception with this default message. That exception has a `Response` property that contains more details about the response, including that message.

Comment: Have you read this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46689006/how-to-show-the-status-code-with-custom-message-in-c ?

Comment: I read a lot of posts with no luck. The one you suggest is for MVC 5.

Comment: Response object contains StatusCode and StatuDescription but, both, are "Unauthorized".

Comment: Sorry, try `GetResponseStream` from the `Response` property of the exception.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a pared-down example which reads your custom message. Your message is returned in the response stream.

```
try
{
    var response = request.GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse;
}
catch (WebException ex) // this exception is thrown because of the 401.
{
    var responseStream = ex.Response.GetResponseStream();
    using (var reader = new StreamReader(responseStream))
    {
        var message = reader.ReadToEnd();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Return an ActionResult

```
Task<ActionResult>
```

You can then wrap up the unauthorized error in an UnauthorizedObjectResult

```
return Unauthorized(new UnauthorizedObjectResult(errorModel));
```