# Getting past 500 "Internal Server Error" when calling from application

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, exception, iis

**EDIT - Included client-side snippet**

I have setup an ASPX endpoint which is being called by an application and unable to read the 500 error I am trying to return.

At this point I am just raising an HttpException to see what comes back and prepare. I am attempting to set the StatusCode and StatusDescription on the Response object (might be redundant), and then throwing an HttpException:

```
    Response.StatusCode = 500
    Response.StatusDescription = "THIS IS A TEST"
    Throw New HttpException("THIS IS A TEST WITH HTTP EXCEPTION")
```

When viewing in the browser (and not just on the server) I can see "THIS IS A TEST WITH HTTP EXCEPTION".

I then have an application which posts to the URL with a Sytem.Net.WebRequest. When I attempt to catch the Exception, the error code is set to 500 and the message is "Internal Server Error" and not my exception message.

Sample POST from application (some parameters used may not be defined in this snippet):

```
            Dim postdatabytes As Byte()
            enc = New System.Text.UTF8Encoding()
            postdatabytes = enc.GetBytes(sData) 
            Dim request As WebRequest = WebRequest.Create(sURL)
            request.Method = "POST"

            request.ContentLength = postdatabytes.Length
            request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"

            Dim dataStream As Stream = request.GetRequestStream()
            dataStream.Write(postdatabytes, 0, postdatabytes.Length)
            dataStream.Close()

            Dim response As WebResponse
            response = request.GetResponse()
```

The GetResponse() triggers the exception and I get the "Internal Server Error".

I have the following web.config:

```
<configuration>
<system.webServer>
    <httpErrors errorMode="Detailed" />
</system.webServer>
<system.web>
    <customErrors mode="Off" />
</system.web>
```

Is this a server configuration issue or am I incorrectly returning an HttpException?

In addition to this, if I wish to return a notational soft error, i.e. "*this entry already exists*" should I be throwing an exception or setting the StatusCode and StatusDescription as above?

Comment: "I then have an application which posts to the URL with a Sytem.Net.WebRequest. When I attempt to catch the Exception, the error code is set to 500 and the message is "Internal Server Error" and not my exception message." So you need to show the source code for that, not merely the server side.

Comment: @LexLi - just edited to show a snippet.

Comment: I succeed to get exception meassge from Web Api in windows application by using ```HttpClient``` and ```HttpResponseMessage``` instead of ```WebRequest``` and ```WebResponse```

Comment: You might get some ideas from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56380537/how-do-i-read-a-custom-error-message-returned-when-httpwebrequest-getresponse-th

Comment: I think you should set status code and description, not throw exception. In IIS, exception was thrown to allow deveploers find out issue. Users only can see exception in screen, not including exception message. So you can custom error page and check execute a url on  this site in Error Page module.