# How to create a custom HTTP status code between 110 - 150 in action result?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, asp.net-mvc-4

I want to add a custom error code like 110, 108 with some message like "Invalid Id". Please suggest how to break the default HTTP status code in ASP.NET

Comment: `string str = "Invalid";
return StatusCode(100, str);` method return is `ActionResult`

Comment: Your tags are confusing - are you using the "full/classic" .NET and ASP.NET MVC 4 - or ASP.NET Core ?? Those are two quite distinct worlds - please clarify ! Also, the 100er range of HTTP status codes is for **information** - not for error - those should be in the 400er range.... having a HTTP status code of 108 and making this an **error** goes against the *Principle Of Least Surprise* and any users of your API will scratch their heads and be confused....

Comment: Do you just want to return the json content corresponding to the custom status code and error message, or do you want to change the Http status code at the same time? And are you implementing it in core or mvc? These are two different projects.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly you can't use 1xx range of HTTP status codes to show error.
1xx Informational 
2xx Success 
3xx Redirection 
4xx Client Error 
5xx Server Error 
You can learn more about HTTP status codes [here](https://www.restapitutorial.com/httpstatuscodes.html) as well. 
Secondly as you want to create custom code, I think this will answer your question [How to show the status code with custom message in c#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46689006)

Answer (score 0):

For example :

```
public ActionResult TestError(string id) // id = error code
{
    Response.StatusCode = 400; // Replace .AddHeader
    var error = new Error();  // Create class Error() w/ prop
    error.ErrorID = 123;
    error.Level = 2;
    error.Message = "You broke the Internet!";

    return Json(error, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```